# Is it possible to copy any file character by character?

Tags: file, filestream, file-copying

I mean file with any extensions from `mp4` to `docx` with a **filestream**. If it's possible, how can I make it?

Comment: **Not Clear Enough** to figure out what you need. Please clarify your question

Answer (score 1):

In Java e.g. you can use a [FileInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) for reading binary data and a [FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) for writing it. It will be a 1:1 binary copy.